# Open excel file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to open a Excel(.xls) file from asp.net.The code i am using is given here.It is showing a save as dialog box which i don't want .Please help me !!!

```
  Response.ContentType = "application/xls";
  Response.Flush();
  Response.WriteFile(fileName);
  Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  response.addheader and use "binarywirte" instead of "writeFile" to your code like below sample code(working code) ...

```
   System.IO.FileStream fs = null;
        fs = System.IO.File.Open(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

        byte[] btFile = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(btFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.BinaryWrite(btFile);
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ultimately controlled through file associations in the operating system.You can modify registry settings on a per machine basis to achieve this result.

You would need to change the **subkeys** under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes** that relate to excel.  Specifically you have to add the following value:

```
Name=BrowserFlags; Type=REG_DWORD; Value=8
```